# How can I set/modify parent class variables through child class?

Tags: php, oop

**Edit:**

I am sorry. I was just able to do what I am trying to do by passing the parent class as $this in my child class call. `$load = new Child_Class( $this );` pretty sure it looks a bit ugly but serves my purpose

So the basic idea is that I am writing a parent class that has some variables e.g.

```
class Parent_Class {

    public $amount = 0;
    public $user_id = 0;

    public function __construct() {

          // I load the child to do some work and update amount.
          $load = new Child_Class();
    }

}
```

And then I have a child class. I'm trying to update the Parent class $amount variable from within child class yet access it from parent class variable.

```
class Child_Class extends Parent_Class {

    public function __construct() {

       // How can I do this?
       parent::$amount = 50; // update the amount in parent
    }

}
```

The problem is that I am trying to access the data like this:

```
$parent = new Parent_Class();
$amount = $parent->amount;
```

But this does not work and only `$parent::$amount` (static) works. Is there a way to make it work as non-static variable?

SO my parent class was initated from:

```
$parent = new Parent_Class();
```

I make some work in child class and need to return updated amount via

```
$parent->amount;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused about how classes work

```
parent::$amount = 50; // update the amount in parent
```

You don't need to do that unless you're redeclaring `$amount` in your child AND your parent class only looks to itself for that value (i.e. `self::$amount`). Your child inherits everything that isn't `private` so you can just use

```
$this->amount = 50;
```

Comment: I am new to classes so please yea accept my ignorance. What I am trying to do is Overwrite the variables in parent so I can access them from parent. e.g. Parent amount = 0, I am trying to make the amount change within child class but STILL access it from parent. I tried doing $this->amount = 50 but it returns 0 which is the parent amount. So I think i am trying to redeclare amount? I am a bit confused

Comment: I am indeed trying to update the amount from child class (The amount which is in parent) and not trying to access it only from child. Hope that's clear :)

Comment: When your child class instantiates itself it implicitly instantiates the parent and all the methods as well. So there's no need to redeclare them or set them separately

Comment: I think I'm silly or can't ask properly. You know I set the amount in parent as 0. Then i use the child class to do some operations then alter the amount and print the result back via the parent class. So parent amount = 0, then do some operations in child then set amount = 50 then be able to just get the new amount via "parent" class $parent->amount.

Comment: It sounds like you want to instantiate the parent and child separately tho. That kind of defeats the purpose of having a child class tho

Comment: Oh actually you're right, It just does not make sense why I use child class for that purpose. I am confused about class relationships as you said. Thanks